# How to generate a ProgressBar programmatically in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a progress bar programmatically in Xamarin.Android. I need it to be equivalent to the following progress bar created in the axml file.

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_below="@+id/framelauout"
        android:indeterminateTint="#5daa30"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

How would i accomplish this in a c# class using android Xamarin.Android platform?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you experience? var progressBar = new ProgressBar(context) {prop1 = value,prop2 = value}; progressBar.LayoutParams = new ConstraintLayoutParams(ViewGroup.FillParent,ViewGroup.WrapContent){SomeOtherProps = ...} and so on...

Comment: I want to used it in different views, not only on one view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating it in xaml, Create it programatically anywhere in the app, with preferred position on screen.

```
var _pbr = ProgressBar(this, "b");
_pbr.Show();
//your code here
 _pbr.Hide();
```

ProgressBar method

```
public ProgressDialog ProgressBar(Context context, string position)
{

    var pbr = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pbr.SetCancelable(false);
    pbr.Indeterminate = true;
    pbr.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
    switch (position.ToLower())
    {
        case "c":
            pbr.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
            break;
        case "b":
            pbr.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Bottom);
            break;

    }
    pbr.SetMessage("please wait..");
    return pbr;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful but I'm specifically interested in the progress bar not the progress dialog.

Comment: Progress bar mean horizontal view not circular?

Comment: Can we see the same sample but with ProgressBar instead as asked ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Olivier MATROT- I didn't get you point, could you be more clear

Comment: The progress dialog is an obsolete class. I am trying to build this functionality with the progress bar class instead. So instead of Android.App.ProgressDialog I would like to accomplish the above given example with Android.Widget.ProgressBar.